# DRF Annotate all stores that an author have a book seeling

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I'm trying to annotate an information in my `Author` API: All Stores where that author have a book.  I have the following models:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books')

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

In my `get_queryset` method i've tried to do something like:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Author.objects.all().annotate(
            stores=F('books__stores__name')
        )

        return qs
```

but stores return just one name of a store, and not a list of stores. can someone tell me what I'm done wrong ?

Edit:
my current Serializer:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    stores = serializers.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'books', 'stores']
```